# How to organize an overlapping ordinal variables?

Tags: categorical-data, ordinal-data, data-preprocessing, overlapping-data

I am analyzing some data with attributes about how long it takes to commute, and it is an overlapping ordinal variable like the following:

| Time | Number of People |
| --- | --- |
| 1-5 minutes | 10 |
| 6-10 minutes | 24 |
| less than 10 minutes | 15 |
| 11-20 minutes | 32 |
| Between 10-15 minutes | 3 |
| More than 15 minutes | 30 |
| 21-30 minutes | 4 |

As you can see, the variables overlap. How can I transform it into either an ordinal or even numeric variables for further analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a great exemplar of Ronald Fisher's quote:

> "To call in the statistician after the experiment is done may be no
> more than asking him to perform a post-mortem examination: he may be
> able to say what the experiment died of."

If at all possible, I would scrap this and start over.

But that's probably not the answer you want. So, what can you do?

You can lump the first three into "Ten minutes or less" and the last four into "more than 10 minutes".  One category is "between 10 and 15", so my division isn't perfect, but it's as good as I can think of.

Comment: Thank you. 
I think this maybe the way to go.

Comment: Glad to help. Since you are new here, can I remind you that it is good practice to upvote and/or "accept" answers that meet your needs? This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (And if you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

And welcome to the site!